# Bar chart using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, data-visualization

Given a csv file with two columns I want to plot bar graph to show the number of tweets posted using iPhone, mac, ipad and android in decreasing order using R. Device name is embed with text problem with remove text and plot bar graph.

```
data <- structure(list(Device = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
        3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("Twitter for iphone", "Twitter for android", "Twitter for mac", "Twitter for android", "Twitter for ipad", 
                      "Twitter for android"), class = "factor"),Text = structure(c(5L, 
        3L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Matches is abandoned", "Policy changes in finance", 
        "Launches of new satellites", "Premium policy get activate by company abc", 
        "Technology makes trend",
        "Weather forecasting by xyz"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        -6L))
```

I will get an error using R in plotting the bar graph using given dataset.

Comment: Hi there, not sure I understand what you mean. Where are the counts (i.e. the actual number of tweets by category) you wish to plot?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @TheDeshBhakt! Please accept one of the answer provided if one solves your problem. If not please adjust your question to make it clearer what you are up to.

Comment: @ThomasNeitmann Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

If you want to plot the counts of tweets from each device you can use `bar_chart()` from the [`{ggcharts}`](https://thomas-neitmann.github.io/ggcharts/index.html) package.

```r
data$Device <- as.character(data$Device)
ggcharts::bar_chart(data, Device)
```

[image]

The resulting plot is a `ggplot` so you can further customize it using any `{ggplot2}` function.

Answer (score 1):

Your data frame contains two factors with raw information. A bar plot requires a number per category to plot. So, you could do this.

```
barplot(table(data$Device))
barplot(table(data$Text))
```

`table` counts the occurrencies of the factor levels and feeds them into the bar plot.

Answer (score 1):

(ggplot approach)
You can use below code:

```
library(ggplot2)
data$only_Device<-gsub(".*for ","", data$Device)
a<-table(data$only_Device) %>% as.data.frame() %>% arrange(desc(Freq))
a$Var1<-as.factor(a$Var1)
ggplot(a, aes(x = reorder(Var1, -Freq), y = Freq)) +geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]